# Calling instance method to access IBOutlet instance from another class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, iboutlet

I've been searching through a lot of forum but it's still driving me crazy.
i don't understand how to access IBOutlet instance for example of class 'A' from class 'B' which is attempting to change the value let's say the instance type is IBOutlet NSTextLabel *progressStatus with stringValue "Capturing" want to change to "Recognizing". It can be called only from the instance method of classA it self, but not from another class.

```
@interface classA : NSView
{
      NSTextField *progressStatus;
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *progressStatus;
-(void)recognizeStatus;
@end    

#import "classA.h"

@implementation classA
@synthesize progressStatus;

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
      [self recognizeStatus];     //successfully change the value inside progressStatus
}

-(void)recognizeStatus
{
      [progressStatus setStringValue:@"Recognizing"];
      NSLog(@"Progress Status : %@",progressStatus.stringValue);
}

- (void)captureOutput:(QTCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputVideoFrame:(CVImageBufferRef)videoFrame withSampleBuffer:(QTSampleBuffer *)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(QTCaptureConnection*)connection
{
      //code to convert videoFrame to IplImage type named frameImage

      BOOL faceDetected = [classB faceDetection:frameImage];
}
@end

#import "classA.h"

@interface classB : NSObject
{

}
+(BOOL)faceDetection:(IplImage*)source;
@end

#import "classA.h"
#import "classB.h"

@implementation classB
+(BOOL)faceDetection:(IplImage*)source
{
       classA *status = [[classA alloc] init];    
       [status recognizeStatus];                     //no changes with the value inside progressStatus

       //return bool type
}
@end
```

Comment: `//this is not worked!` does not help us understand your problem. What did you expect to happen and what did you actually see? A crash, a compiler error, the UI not changing when you expected it to?

Comment: it didn't change in the UI even the method recognizeStatus is not called at a time in class B. i expect to call recognizeStatus method successfully so the NSTextField in class A change it's text field from "Capturing" to "Recognizing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `classB`'s class method `faceDetection:`you initialize an instance of `classA` which derives from `NSView`, but you do not add the instance to the view hierarchy.  Further, in initializing the instance of `classA` you aren't loading the view from a nib, so the instance of `classA` `status` likely has a nil `progressStatus`.

I suspect you may be trying to access an instance of `classA` that was already initialized and added to the view hierarchy elsewhere; but initializing another instance won't provide you with a reference to the original instance.

Comment: yes indeed, i don't know how to add the instance to the view hierarchy and reference it to the original instance. i saw from another posting to use delegate, but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: It depends on whether `classB` holds a reference to the existing instance of `classA`.  If it does not, then you need to redesign the relationship between the two classes. A delegate pattern still requires a referencing relationship, albeit weak, between the two classes.  Alternatively, you could use `NSNotificationCenter` to post a notification from `classB`; and `classA` could register for those notifications.

Comment: okay i will try to use notification center. do you have a sample of this?